# How to get the Facebook user details in php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am login with the facebook using the javascript sdk .Once the user is loggedin then in server side i am using this code to fetch the user details ,but it is not create the session,but in javascript it is created the session.

This is the my javascript code

```
$('body').delegate(".fblogin","click",function(){
    FB.init({appId: '', xfbml: true, cookie: true,oauth      : true,});
     FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
```

once the user is loggedin then i am call the ajax function to get the friends but it is not creating the session in php side.

the PHP code is

```
if(!$this->facebook->logged_in()){
 echo '<li class="fblogin"><img src="http://naveen/app/assets/img/connect-with-facebook.png" class="ac_even"></li>';
}
else{
    $this->load->library('facebook');
    $fbfriends =  $this->facebook->call('get', 'me/friends');
    $friends=$fbfriends->data;
}
```

Every time it shows the fb login image.

Can any body help how to solve this problem.
I am not very well in english.If any mistakes is there excuse me.

Comment: How exactly are you using the PHP SDK on your server? Also what version of the SDK are you using... Your syntax doesn't look like the PHP SDK...

Comment: i am using the codeigniter php sdk with facebook-php-3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's a session issue, try switching to PHP native sessions & see if it works.

A native PHP session replacement library is available for download (look it up through google).

Hopes this would solve your issue.